# Aligning text objects next to each other - KineticJS

Tags: html, kineticjs

I have text objects and label objects which are seperate. They need to be aligned next to each other when being drawn. I'm adding the x and y co-ordinates but the objects are off by some pixels and are not on the same line. Here is my code. I have added the picture of how the text is being rendered.

```
![var extractedSubString  = text.substring(currentTextOffset,value.begin-1)
            console.log(extractedSubString)
            currentTextOffset += value.end

             var complexText = new Kinetic.Text({
                x:x,
                y:y,
                width:3000,
                text: extractedSubString,
                fontSize: 14,
                fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                fill: '#555',
                align: 'left'
            });

            x += complexText.getTextWidth()
            y += complexText.getHeight()

            group.add(complexText)
            var simpleLabel = new Kinetic.Label({
                opacity: 0.75,
                x:x,
                y:y,
                text: {
                    text: value.data,
                    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                    fontSize: 14,
                    padding: 5,
                    fill: '#555'
                },
                rect: {
                    fill: labelColor
                }
            });

            group.add(simpleLabel)
            x +=simpleLabel.getWidth()
            y +=simpleLabel.getHeight()][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Edited:]

**How to append Kinetic Labels and Texts while aligning them in a simulated “textarea”**

This is the key code that sets the X/Y of additional labels/texts.

To get the **valid** text width it must be calculated after creating the object.

```
var newWidth=label.getWidth();
```

Keep track of the amount of horizontal line space used by text so far.

Start a new line if previously line width + new text width will cause the text to overflow the maximum line width.

To start a new line, increment the “Y” position of the line.

```
if( accumLineWidth + newWidth > maxLineWidth ){
    verticalAlign+=lineHeight;
    accumLineWidth=leftMargin;
}
```

And finally, set the X/Y positions of the new text.  And add the current text width to the accumulator.

```
// set X
label.setX(accumLineWidth);
accumLineWidth+=width;

// set Y
label.setY(verticalAlign-label.getHeight()/2);
layer.add(label);
layer.draw();
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/vkG7X/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #container{border:1px solid red; width:350px;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

     var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 200
      });
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      stage.add(layer);

      var leftMargin=20;
      var maxLineWidth=300;
      var lineHeight=25;

      // new labels/texts will begin at accumLineWidth
      var accumLineWidth=leftMargin;

      // new labels/texts will align themselves to verticalAlign
      var verticalAlign=25;

      function appendLabel(labelText){

          var label = new Kinetic.Label({
            text: {
              text: labelText,
              fontFamily: 'Verdana',
              fontSize: 18,
              padding: 5,
              fill: 'white'
            },
            rect: {
              fill: 'blue'
            }
          });

          // need to calc width/height AFTER creation
          // set width and check for newline
          var width=label.getWidth();
          if(accumLineWidth+width>maxLineWidth){
              verticalAlign+=lineHeight;
              accumLineWidth=leftMargin;
          }
          // set X
          label.setX(accumLineWidth);
          accumLineWidth+=width;
          // set Y
          label.setY(verticalAlign-label.getHeight()/2);
          layer.add(label);
          layer.draw();
      }


      function appendText(newText){

          var text = new Kinetic.Text({
            text: newText,
            fontSize: 18,
            fontFamily: 'Verdana',
            fill: 'blue'
          });

          // need to calc width/height AFTER creation
          // set width and check for newline
          var width=text.getWidth();
          if(accumLineWidth+width>maxLineWidth){
              verticalAlign+=lineHeight;
              accumLineWidth=leftMargin;
          }
          // set X
          text.setX(accumLineWidth);
          accumLineWidth+=width;
          // set Y
          text.setY(verticalAlign-text.getHeight()/2);
          layer.add(text);
          layer.draw();
      }


      // testing

      var counter=0;

      $("#label").click(function(){ appendLabel("Label"+counter++); });
      $("#text").click(function(){ appendText(" text"+counter++); });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <button id="label">Add label</button>
    <button id="text">Add text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Example is good. I have lots of text chunks which I have to display, how will I calculate the effective x and y for them. Right now you are assigning them statically but I need to caluclate them based on the chunks of text which I'm getting.

Comment: Now that your 1 label object and 1 text object are aligned, couldn't you just append your new chunks to your existing text object:  myTextObject.setText( myTextObject.getText()+" "+newText );

Comment: The problem is I have too many text objects to worry about. There can be 100 or more than 10000 at a given time

Comment: Maybe I'm not fully understanding your project...Are you saying you want each new chunk to always be a **separate** label+textChunk.  I'm assuming you will position each separate label+textChunk by supplying it an X/Y coordinate.

Comment: Here is the problem. I have lots of text chunks which contain the actual text and then there are also labels and in some cases I may not even have labels. I have to display all the text chunks including labels as if it would be displayed in a text area and hence I have to calculate X and y for each chunk

Comment: I think I understand.  See my edited answer that shows how to align random incoming labels or text into a simulated "textarea".